# How to make a full width Bootstrap button responsive?

Tags: button, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have created a full-width/block Bootstrap button. Works great in desktop mode, but I can't figure out how to make it scale down in mobile - it just cuts off halfway instead of sizing down. Any suggestions?

```css
#element228866067:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #ffbc39!important
}
```

```html
<div class="ButtonBlock ss-ui-bootstrap" style="text-align:center">

  <a id="element228866067" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" style="color: #ffffff; padding: 20px 0 20px 0; background-color: #ff5e54; border-color: #fff8c2; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px; border-style: solid"> <strong>Get the Award-Winning Books and Give Yourself an Unfair Advantage in Life!</strong> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Yes, thank you for answering.<div class="ButtonBlock ss-ui-bootstrap" style="text-align:center">
<style>
#element228866067:hover{color:#fff!important;background-color:#ffbc39!important}
</style>
<a id="element228866067" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" style="color: #ffffff; padding: 20px 0 20px 0; background-color: #ff5e54; border-color: #fff8c2; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px; border-style: solid">
<strong>Get the Award-Winning Books and Give Yourself an Unfair Advantage in Life!</strong>
</a>
</div>

Comment: Paste this code in question. It works fine so there has to be something else in site CSS that prevents scaling. It can be min-width or disabled text wraping. https://jsfiddle.net/2ukLcxd4/

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for the suggestion. I found text wrapping disabled and fixed it as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284153/how-to-get-a-responsive-button-in-bootstrap-3, the second answer.